# How do I overwrite value in nested dictionary with if else statement nicely

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a nested dictionary which I want to store some information in it.

> d = {0: {'a': None, 'b': None, 'c': None},
>               1: {'a': None, 'b': None, 'c': None},
>               2: {'a': None, 'b': None, 'c': None}}

I want to rewrite value 'a', 'b' and 'c' every time the program received a result.

If the value 'a' is none, it should fill 'a' only,  else if 'a' is not none and 'b' is none, fill 'b',  and if 'a' and 'b' is none, fill 'c',  if all is filled shift everything to the front and fill the 'c'.

My code goes like this:

```
    a_conditon = d.get(index, {}).get('a') is None
    b_conditon = d.get(index, {}).get('b') is None
    c_conditon = d.get(index, {}).get('c') is None

    if (a_conditon):
        d.setdefault(index, {})['a']= bool(random.getrandbits(1))

    elif ((not a_conditon) and b_conditon):
        d.setdefault(index, {})['b']= bool(random.getrandbits(1))

    elif ((not a_conditon) and (not b_conditon) and c_conditon):
        d.setdefault(index, {})['c']= bool(random.getrandbits(1))

    elif ((not a_conditon) and (not b_conditon) and (not c_conditon)):
        d.setdefault(index, {})['a']= d.get(index, {}).get('b')
        d.setdefault(index, {})['b']= d.get(index, {}).get('c')
        d.setdefault(index, {})['c']= bool(random.getrandbits(1))
```

However, I got it straight away fill up all 3 entries. Can someone help point out to me on this?  I'm not sure where did it go wrong

Comment: What are you using `setdefault` for? It might be worth considering using a `defaultdict`.

Comment: i don't see a problem with the output.

Comment: @Marcos this will loop multiple times. Example in the first loop all entries will be none, when it received the first result, it should overwrite value 'a' only, but this code overwrite all value a, b and c with the result. and somehow it  overwrite the same result on every index. value a for index 1 until 10 will be the same. same goes with b and c

Comment: Can you share the loop that you mentioned about? When are the index values changing?

Answer (score 0):

I tried out the code based on the logic as described by you and put it in a loop for index values of 0,1,2. It seems to work fine for me. Can you validate the loop and that the condition check `a_condition`, `b_condition` and `c_condition` are evaluated every time in the loop? Also, there are 2 loops in the example:

1. The outer loop iterates over the index values
2. The inner loop iterates 4 times to run the 4 desired states

For instance, in the first loop, for the index value of 0, the first state is executed to produce the output `{0: {'a': True, 'b': None, 'c': None}, 1: {'a': None, 'b': None, 'c': None}, 2: {'a': None, 'b': None, 'c': None}}`, followed by the next state `{0: {'a': True, 'b': False, 'c': None}, 1: {'a': None, 'b': None, 'c': None}, 2: {'a': None, 'b': None, 'c': None}}`

Here's the code and the output as desired.

```
while(index <=2):
    count = 3
    while(count>=0):
        a_conditon = d.get(index, {}).get('a') is None
        b_conditon = d.get(index, {}).get('b') is None
        c_conditon = d.get(index, {}).get('c') is None

        if (a_conditon):
            d.setdefault(index, {})['a']= bool(random.getrandbits(1))

        elif ((not a_conditon) and b_conditon):
            d.setdefault(index, {})['b']= bool(random.getrandbits(1))

        elif ((not a_conditon) and (not b_conditon) and c_conditon):
            d.setdefault(index, {})['c']= bool(random.getrandbits(1))

        elif ((not a_conditon) and (not b_conditon) and (not c_conditon)):
            d.setdefault(index, {})['a']= d.get(index, {}).get('b')
            d.setdefault(index, {})['b']= d.get(index, {}).get('c')
            d.setdefault(index, {})['c']= bool(random.getrandbits(1))
        print(d)
        count -=1
    index += 1
```

Output on running for index values of 0,1,2

```
{0: {'a': True, 'b': None, 'c': None}, 1: {'a': None, 'b': None, 'c': None}, 2: {'a': None, 'b': None, 'c': None}}
{0: {'a': True, 'b': False, 'c': None}, 1: {'a': None, 'b': None, 'c': None}, 2: {'a': None, 'b': None, 'c': None}}
{0: {'a': True, 'b': False, 'c': True}, 1: {'a': None, 'b': None, 'c': None}, 2: {'a': None, 'b': None, 'c': None}}
{0: {'a': False, 'b': True, 'c': False}, 1: {'a': None, 'b': None, 'c': None}, 2: {'a': None, 'b': None, 'c': None}}
{0: {'a': False, 'b': True, 'c': False}, 1: {'a': False, 'b': None, 'c': None}, 2: {'a': None, 'b': None, 'c': None}}
{0: {'a': False, 'b': True, 'c': False}, 1: {'a': False, 'b': False, 'c': None}, 2: {'a': None, 'b': None, 'c': None}}
{0: {'a': False, 'b': True, 'c': False}, 1: {'a': False, 'b': False, 'c': True}, 2: {'a': None, 'b': None, 'c': None}}
{0: {'a': False, 'b': True, 'c': False}, 1: {'a': False, 'b': True, 'c': False}, 2: {'a': None, 'b': None, 'c': None}}
{0: {'a': False, 'b': True, 'c': False}, 1: {'a': False, 'b': True, 'c': False}, 2: {'a': True, 'b': None, 'c': None}}
{0: {'a': False, 'b': True, 'c': False}, 1: {'a': False, 'b': True, 'c': False}, 2: {'a': True, 'b': False, 'c': None}}
{0: {'a': False, 'b': True, 'c': False}, 1: {'a': False, 'b': True, 'c': False}, 2: {'a': True, 'b': False, 'c': False}}
{0: {'a': False, 'b': True, 'c': False}, 1: {'a': False, 'b': True, 'c': False}, 2: {'a': False, 'b': False, 'c': True}}
```